# C++ Does Const_Cast induce new variable?

Tags: c++, const-cast

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        const int a = 2;
        const int *p = &a;
        int *p2 = const_cast<int*>(p);
        *p2=5;
        char *p3 = (char *)&a;
        cout << "p2 is" << *p2 << endl;
        cout << "p2 address " << p2 << endl;
        cout << "a is " << a << endl;
        cout << "a address " << &a << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Hi all!

According to the output, *p2 and a has different values, *p2 is 5 and a is 2.

However, p2 and &a are the same. I'm confused...

Could you please help me understand where this is the case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to change a constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Undefined behavior means that anything can happen. Including this.

#### 5.2.11 Const cast [expr.const.cast]

> 7) [ Note: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through the pointer, lvalue or pointer
>   to data member resulting from a `const_cast` that casts away a const-qualifier<sup>73</sup> may produce undefined
>   behavior (7.1.6.1). —end note ]

The underlying reason might be that the compiler, seeing how `a` is `const`, optimizes `cout << "a is " << a << endl;` to a simple `cout << "a is " << 2 << endl;`.

For example, **even in a debug build**, I get:

```
        cout << "a is " << a << endl;
00CE1581  mov         esi,esp  
00CE1583  mov         eax,dword ptr [__imp_std::endl (0CFD30Ch)]  
00CE1588  push        eax  
00CE1589  mov         edi,esp  
//...
00CE158B  push        2 
//...
00CE158D  push        offset string "a is " (0CE7840h)  
00CE1592  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (0CFD308h)]  
00CE1598  push        ecx  
00CE1599  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (0CE1159h)  
00CE159E  add         esp,8  
00CE15A1  mov         ecx,eax  
00CE15A3  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (0CFD304h)]  
00CE15A9  cmp         edi,esp  
00CE15AB  call        @ILT+415(__RTC_CheckEsp) (0CE11A4h)  
00CE15B0  mov         ecx,eax  
00CE15B2  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (0CFD300h)]  
00CE15B8  cmp         esi,esp  
00CE15BA  call        @ILT+415(__RTC_CheckEsp) (0CE11A4h)
```

I highlighted the essential part - `2` is pushed directly on the argument stack of `operator<<`, instead of the value of `a` being read.

Comment: +1 for explanation via compiled code.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your help!! BTW, rather than give me fish, could you explain a bit how to fish? How to debug using assembly like this? Could you give some hint? Thanks!

Comment: @user1582802 depends on the IDE/tools you have. I use MS visual studio, and you can switch to assembly during debugging - right clock -> show disassembly.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you've gone astray:

```
int main() {
        const int a = 2;
        const int *p = &a;
        int *p2 = const_cast<int*>(p);
        *p2=5;
```

On the last line here, you've assigned a variable thu a pointer that points to something that *is actually const*.  That is, `a` is `const`.  `p2` points to `a`.  You can't change the value of `a`, even through `p2`, without invoking Undefined Behavior.